# Jasmine 2.0 Test with Nested Angular Promise

Tags: javascript, timeout, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

I have a test that requires one promise to be run and later in its `then` handler another promise returning function is run.

The first promise resolves, and a successful call is made to the next function which returns a promise.  However, the then handler for that second promise never fires.

Is there another way to test nested promises using Jasmine 2.0?

Example problem:

```
describe("nested promise suite", function () {
        var prom1 = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve('prom1');
            }, 500)
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        var prom2 = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve('prom2');
            }, 500);
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        iit("nested promise test", function (done) {
            prom1()
                .then(function (result) {
                    console.log('prom1 result ', result);
                    prom2()
                        .then(function (result2) {
                            console.log('prom2 result ', result2);
                        })
                        .finally(function() {
                            console.log('you did it');
                        })
                })
                .finally(done);  //this causes promise one to resolve properly but unsure of how to make the second promise resolve properly
            $timeout.flush();
        })
    });
```

Comment: You should always `return` your promises from `then()` callbacks.

Comment: Don't use the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) already returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the problem in your original code as well, but in this example, your second console.log doesn't fire because `prom2` adds a new timeout after the first has been flushed. The promise from `prom2` then waits for this new timeout to flush, which never happens:

1. `prom1()` is called
2. The first promise and timeout are created
3. The first timeout is flushed, resolving the first promise
4. The then() block is triggered, calling `prom2()`
5. The second promise and timeout are created
6. `done()` is called.

You can try adding a second `$timeout.flush();` call right after the one that's already there, which will flush the second timeout, resolve the second promise, and log the missing messages.